# External Drag & drop items to the calendar react

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-calendar

I am using [react-calendar-timeline](https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/react-calendar-timeline) for my project. I have requirements where i need to drag and drop item(s)from the external source to the calendar timeline. Currently react-calendar-timeline library doesn't support such a thing from my findings.

Question is how can i drag and drop outside item(s) to the calendar using react-calendar-timeline library? I am pretty sure it's doable but can't find out myself.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone guide me or provide me a hint.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution? If not then let me know. I have implemented same with the help of react-dnd.

Comment: @Dhruvinmodi could you please describe your implementation? Thanks

Comment: How we can implement this feature? Can you please please help me here @Dhruvinmodi

Comment: @PrakashP You can use react-dnd. One container will have items that needs to be dragged. Once container could your div where you want to drop.  Drop container could be any element. While dragging you need to track mouse position ( x, y ) with respect to your drop container. You need to pass this details to drop dive component to update drop components behavior. I hope, I am making sense..!